# How to run Express on io.js

Tags: javascript, express, frameworks, io.js

So Node.js was forked late last year and the forked version is io.js.

I can't find anything of a setup guide on the docs. I'm fairly new, anyone know how I can setup io.js using Express web framework? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually `io.js` wasn't released yet. First release will be at January 13th(or 14rth) (see [here](https://github.com/iojs/io.js/issues/28)). At this time the best you can do to setup `io.js` is to clone its [repository](https://github.com/iojs/io.js):

```
git clone https://github.com/iojs/io.js
```

and try to build it manually. On Unix/Max it looks like:

```
./configure
make
make install
```

But I do not recommend you to do this. Beware: now very active preparation for the first release is going on. Lots of commits with possibly breaking changes. So better wait less then one week until first official `io.js` version will be released.

Answer (score 6):

Do the steps in answer 1, then create an index.js file like this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/resources', express.static(__dirname + '/resources'));

app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.send('hello world');
    res.end();
});

app.listen(3000);
```

and a `package.json` file like this

```
{
  "name": "iojsexpress",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Get express working with iojs",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.10.7"
  }
}
```

and then run the following commands

```
npm install
iojs index.js
```

and visit localhost port 3000 in your browser and you should see "hello world"