# Use Express.js with io.js?

Tags: express, io.js

Does it still make sense to use Express.js with io.js or does io.js have some sort of built-in functionality now that Express.js gave or do we still rely on Express.js.  I mean Express.js doesn't extend io.js, it extends node.js.

I'm trying to figure out how you'd do the Web Server part if using io.js.

Comment: You should look at this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871309/how-to-run-express-on-io-js?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Think of io.js just as a new release of node.js. They have essentially identical feature sets and are essentially drop-in compatible with each other. You use any library from npm in the same matter on either io.js or node.js. Express.js and most other libraries in npm work on both just fine. There are still many npm modules that contain binary add-ons that don't yet work with io.js, but that should sort itself out quickly enough.

Comment: thanks so I guess you'll find out when those binary add-ons don't work when they blow up with errors in the command-line?

Comment: Yeah they'll fail during `npm install` until the author makes the necessary updates. For a web app, there's not many essential modules with binary add-ons though. Most things have pure-js versions or are actively maintained (DB drivers for popular DBs, etc).